# date and time in textbox googlescripts

Tags: date, time, textbox

Hello im new with Programming and with googlescripts i hope some can help me, i make as a test  app just a simple textbox with a button and i want to change the value of the textbox and show the date and the time  when i clicking on the button , i have trid to write this code but i dont know where is the wrong in it 
thank you all

```
 function doGet() {
      var app=UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('test app');
      var pan1=app.createHorizontalPanel();
      app.add(pan1);
      var txt1=app.createTextBox().setId(txt1);
      var btn1=app.createButton().setText('start').setId('btn1');
      btn1.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("now"));
      pan1.add(txt1);
      pan1.add(btn1);
      return app;
}

function now() {
     var app =UiApp.getActiveApplication();
     app.getElementById("txt1").setText(new Date());
     return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following line

`var txt1=app.createTextBox().setId(txt1);`

to

`var txt1=app.createTextBox().setId('txt1');`